# Using BCP to create XML files produces files with invalid encoding for non-ASCII characters

Tags: sql-server, xml, character-encoding, bcp

Reproducing issue, SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.FooTable(SomeString NVARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO dbo.FooTable(SomeString)
VALUES('Degree symbol is °');
DECLARE @Code NVARCHAR(4000) = N'BCP "SELECT (SELECT SomeString FROM dbo.FooTable FOR XML PATH(''Foo''), ROOT(''BAR''), TYPE )"  QUERYOUT "F:\Output\File.XML" -c -C RAW -T ';

EXEC xp_cmdshell @Code;

DROP TABLE dbo.FooTable;
```

It creates file with following content:

```
<BAR><Foo><SomeString>Degree symbol is °</SomeString></Foo></BAR>
```

Such files are not recognized as valid XML files by Internet Explorer and Firefox (Chrome yields error `error on line 1 at column 23: Encoding error`). If I open them with Notepad and save as Unicode (little endian) - it opens and validates.

Update:

> changing `bcp` options to `-T -w -r -t` seems to make XML valid for most XML consumers, but not Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one -

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.##t') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##t

SELECT x = (
    SELECT x
    FROM (
        VALUES (N'Degree symbol is °')
    ) t(x)
    FOR XML PATH('Foo'), ROOT('BAR'), TYPE
)
INTO ##t

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000) = 'bcp "SELECT * FROM ##t" queryout "D:\sample.xml" -S ' + @@servername + ' -T -w -r -t'
EXEC sys.xp_cmdshell @sql
```

Just interesting where the root of your issue...

Comment: It's something - this file opens in Firefox, but not in IE, and contains tons of spaces.

Comment: OK - changing `bcp` options to `-T -w -r -t` seems to solve issue for most XML consumers, but not Internet Explorer...